# Is it possible to code action-filter attributes for asp.net web form application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using .NET 4.5, VS 2012 to develop a new ASP.NET web form application. My question: is it possible to write custom action filter attributes for that web form application; for example for checking web request, or checking some event handlers. I know in MVC this is absolutely possible.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always use `HttpModule`. or a base class for all your pages. Other than that, I know nothing. haven't touched WebForms for years.

Comment: So why don't You use mvc?

Comment: @Dmytro. The reason is the new web form project is for ssrs functions and web form application supports ssrs well as my understandings while MVC application does not support post back, .NET server controls, and hence, does not fit well ssrs functions.

Comment: Take a look on this https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WebForms do not have actions so they do not have action filters. You need some other hook mechanism.

I can think of a few:

1. A `Page` base class
2. An `IHttpModule`
3. The `Application_BeginRequest` event and others.